# How to run selenium+chrome on Raspberry PI 4?

Tags: python, selenium, raspberry-pi, selenium-chromedriver

I have a brand-new out of the box Raspberry Pi 4 that I'd like to run python selenium on.  However, I don't have the path to use for this command: any tips?

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome("path-to-chromiumdriver")
```

I am also happy to run it with Firefox if someone has the path for that!

Thanks,
/yga

Comment: im so fricking dumb I cant even load selenium in mac

Answer (score 38):

Aha - looks like https://ivanderevianko.com/2020/01/selenium-chromedriver-for-raspberrypi has the answer!

```
sudo apt-get install chromium-chromedriver
```

And then in the python code:

```
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display

display = Display(visible=0, size=(1600, 1200))
display.start()
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver')
```

(I wanted to run a headless version; hence the pyvirtualdisplay)

Comment: For headless you don't need any display, just pass `--headless` option to `Chrome()` function in the `options` parameter.

Comment: it's interesting though because some sites block headless browsers, so it can a be way to get through the protection

Comment: `apt source chromium-chromedriver` sadly gives `E: Unable to find a source package for chromium-browser`