# How to solve 'OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error' when running Python3 script on Raspberry pi 4?

Tags: python-3.x, linux, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, raspberry-pi4

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

mobile_emulation = {
    "deviceName": "iPhone X" 
}

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

chrome_options.add_experimental_option("mobileEmulation", mobile_emulation)

chrome_path = "/home/pi/Desktop/chromedriver"

driver = selenium.webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_path, options=chrome_options)
```

I am trying to make a python 3 script to work on my `Raspberry Pi 4`, I made the script in `Windows 10`. When running this script on my Raspberry Pi I get the following error:

> OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error: '/home/pi/Desktop/chromedriver'

Does anyone know what the problem could be? I am fairly new to Linux so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The problem is that the program you are running is not the same architecture as the raspberry pi. More info -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38732822/compile-chromedriver-on-arm

Answer (score 0):

The official repository already has the chromedriver package called `chromium-chromedriver`. Just install it by using `apt` command.
You may use `dpkg-query -L chromium-chromedriver` command to find the location of `chromedriver` executable.
BTW, It's a duplicate question, [How to run selenium+chrome on Raspberry PI 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64979042/how-to-run-seleniumchrome-on-raspberry-pi-4).